# Understanding compound types in Coq [Software Foundations]

Tags: coq

[Software Foundations, Basics, Compound Types](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Basics.html#lab25)

I'm trying to understand Coq (day 2, so bear with me, sorry if this is stupid) but I'm looking at the section on compound types in Software Foundations book, and trying to understand this:

```
Inductive rgb : Type :=
  | red : rgb
  | green : rgb
  | blue : rgb.
    Inductive color : Type :=
  | black : color
  | white : color
  | primary : rgb → color.
```

Ok, so these are coinductive types, and my problem is with the definition of "primary". I see that rgb is an enumerated type, and parts of color are, but primary is a function.

The trouble is, it looks like this would be a function that takes rgb, and returns a color, however all of the following examples in that section (monochrome, isred) return booleans.

It also looks like the reflexivity property we've been using up to that point in the book (again, like page 1, bear with me) looks like it takes your tactic, and proves equality; so far all of our examples have been `boolean = boolean` in format.

We'd need a definition of a function that took rgb, and returned color, and we can use reflexivity (because that's all we know on page 1) to solve, right? For unit tests?

Am I on the right track? I guess I'm just confused by the introduction of monochrome and isred, which go back to using the booleans, which doesn't seem like what we're trying to solve for to get a valid example of color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(First:

> these are coinductive types

These are actually *inductive* types, but this was perhaps a typo.)

> it looks like this would be a function that takes rgb, and returns a color

Yes, this is precisely what `primary` is: a function that takes an element of `rgb` and returns an element of `color`.  This is a special kind of function called a *constructor*.  Constructors are different from regular functions in that  every element of an inductive type is obtained from exactly one constructor of that type.  In that first chapter, there are other functions defined by pattern-matching, such as `monochrome`.  That function returns a boolean, but we could have other functions that return `color` as well.  For instance:

```
Definition flip_color (c : color) : color :=
  match c with
  | white => black
  | black => white
  | primary _ => c
  end.
```

> the reflexivity property [...] takes your tactic, and proves equality

A note on terminology: in this context, `reflexivity` is a tactic, and does not take any tactics as arguments.  You are right, however, that it is used to prove equalities.

> We'd need a definition of a function that took rgb, and returned color, and we can use reflexivity (because that's all we know on page 1) to solve, right? For unit tests?

What unit tests are you talking about? This chapter mentions unit tests for `orb` and the `binary` type, but there are no tests for `color`.

Comment: I appreciate the myriad corrections, thank you so much! Yes, there was no unit test for color, but I'm trying to fully understand by experimenting with things as they're introduced, so I thought it would be a wise idea to try to build some unit tests (in the same vein as orb earlier in the chapter). So in this case, we'd just need a constructor called "primary", which we could take rgb as input and provide a color, which could be either black, white, or a generative function that takes rgb as arguments and returns a color?

Comment: I see. For constructor functions like `primary`, there is not much you can prove about them in isolation, precisely because they are so basic.  Usually, you'd show how some other non-primitive function like `flip_color` above interacts with a constructor.

Comment: Ooooh, can you elaborate on that a bit? Oh, wait, let me see if I get it: I could make a lemma that said if I flip a color, I either get its opposite (white/black, black/white, or (flip_color primary), and show that (flip_color primary someRGB) still returns a valid color?